# Tensorflow import issue Python 3.6

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pycharm, python-3.6

I am trying to learn how to create a **Machine Learning Algorithm** by following a tutorial on YouTube and I am currently stuck on the last part of the last video. I got **tensorflow** and **keras** to install without issue, but every time I call **import tensorflow** inside the PyCharm editor it gives me these two back traces

```
Traceback (most recent call last):<br/>
  File "C:\Users\Le Quient LewisII\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
<br/><br/>
  File "C:\Users\Le Quient LewisII\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
<br/><br/>
  File "C:\Users\Le Quient LewisII\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
<br/><br/>
  File "C:\Users\Le Quient LewisII\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
<br/><br/>
  File "C:\Users\Le Quient LewisII\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
<br/><br/>
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
<br/><br/>
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
<br/><br/>
Traceback (most recent call last):<br/>
  File "C:/Users/Le Quient LewisII/PycharmProjects/tensorEnv/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Le Quient LewisII\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
<br/><br/>
  File "C:\Users\Le Quient LewisII\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
<br/><br/>
  File "C:\Users\Le Quient LewisII\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
<br/><br/>
  File "C:\Users\Le Quient LewisII\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
<br/><br/>
  File "C:\Users\Le Quient LewisII\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
<br/><br/>
  File "C:\Users\Le Quient LewisII\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
<br/><br/>
  File "C:\Users\Le Quient LewisII\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)<br/><br/>
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):<br/>
  File "C:\Users\Le Quient LewisII\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
<br/><br/>
  File "C:\Users\Le Quient LewisII\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
<br/><br/>
  File "C:\Users\Le Quient LewisII\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
<br/><br/>
  File "C:\Users\Le Quient LewisII\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
<br/><br/>
  File "C:\Users\Le Quient LewisII\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
<br/><br/>
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL)
initialization routine failed.
```

And I do not know what they mean. I tried **uninstalling and reinstalling tensorflow**, but it still persists. If there is anyone who can assist me with this problem, it would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Did you try googling the error? There seems to be a whole lot of solutions online for it. Which of them did you try?

Comment: I have mainly so far just attempted the uninstall and reinstall method. I have done some more research and a couple threads mention the possibility of the issue is that there might not be enough RAM for the CPU edition on my laptop. I'm thinking of that as the worst-case scenario. Right now, I am going to attempt to going to earlier versions of both tensor, and maybe python if that's the issue. I will keep you posted on my progress

Comment: Okay, so I figured out what my issue was. It was a RAM issue and so I switched to another laptop and it works perfectly fine now. Sorry, for the long wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out what my issue was. It was a RAM issue and so I switched to another laptop and it works perfectly fine now. Sorry, for the long wait